# Are there any practical limits on the level of subclassing?

Tags: java, class, subclass

I'm currently reading topic classes and methods in Java.

Say, I have created different classes and subclasses

```
class Super {
    Number aNumber;
}
class super1 {
Number bNumber;
}
.....
class Sub extends Super {
    Float aNumber;
class sub extends Super1 {
    Float bNumber;
....
}
}
```

How deep can we go like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940800/what-is-the-max-level-of-inheritance-in-java

Comment: it is a bad desigining technique to use a large no. of subclasses. try to break the functionality by using either helper classes or design patterns like Factory or Strategy. To sum up you should not spwan subclasses greater then 2 -3 child classes

Comment: @Blackhat002 it has to be a limitation of the stack size probably..

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in limits to the depth of subclassing - however the JVM will keel over and die with a `StackOverflowError` due to the sheer amount of chained constructor calls that end up on the stack if you take inheritance to the extreme. Your class heirarchy would need to be several hundred classes deep (depending on constructor complexity) for this to happen though. But as noted by others - this would be strongly indicative of a bad design.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think it's a duplicate!